# Can DNS Servers give nearest IP to resolvers?

Tags: domain-name-system

I know what happens when I request `example.com`, but I wish to know is it possible to dispatch nearest server IP determined in a zone file to client? is there any DNS Server doing this? Just like CDN but for IP connections

Comment: You could accomplish this using a "split-view" or "bind-view" or "split-horizon" in DNS.  Explaining how to do that would be a very detailed and complicated answer however.  You may first want to research "split-view" or "split-horizon" DNS.  I assume you are talking about internal or WAN resources.  If you are talking about external DNS records, some DNS providers can do this for you.  Dynect is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before - have a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/118653/how-can-i-send-visitors-to-the-closest-server-using-dns). Otherwise, as suggested in the comments, split horizon may be a solution if your problem relates to a LAN/WAN scenario.

Comment: thx, that link helped me :)